# Show social graph with D3 force layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I want to show a social graph with D3(Date-Driven-Documents) with **three hundred nodes**

The Json data looks like this.

```
{
  "nodes":[
{"name":"node1","group":1},
{"name":"node2","group":1},
{"name":"node3","group":1},
{"name":"node4","group":2},
{"name":"node5","group":2},
{"name":"node6","group":2}
],
"links":[
{"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
{"source":2,"target":0,"value":1},
{"source":1,"target":2,"value":1},
{"source":3,"target":4,"value":1},
{"source":3,"target":5,"value":1},
{"source":4,"target":5,"value":1},
{"source":1,"target":3,"value":1}
]
}
```

Now I meet several problems

1. When I use node.append("image") for every node ,the fps is so low (just like pause and skip)!
2. The graph always goes far away from center , after I use the d3.layout.force().charge(whatever number).distance(10).charge(-100).size([width,height])
3. Now I want to show a social graph with groups , nodes have profile_image and name ! how to make my graph clear ? Need a lot of advise and examples ,Thanks!

Comment: Please do some more research before asking a question. You mention several problems, but do not show us your code or what you have tried to overcome these issues. Especially for the last question it is you who has to do the work -- there're hundreds of examples out there that you can find very easily.

Answer (score 1):

For question 2, use a Bounding Box. A good example can be found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492) in the tick function.

```
 node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(r, Math.min(w - r, d.x)); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(r, Math.min(h - r, d.y)); });

link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
```

This prevents the nodes from moving beyond the bounding box.

Also, you can set the gravity to keep the nodes centralized. As Lars mentioned in his comment, there is no code listed to help you further.